# Error: CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present in ionic 4

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'myURL' from origin 'localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Source code

```
this.http.get(login_url ).subscribe(data => {
      this.responseArray = data;
      console.log(this.responseArray.SINGLE_HOTEL_APP[0].success);
    });
```

I am using ionic [HTTP](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http) plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you put in your web api header ('Allow-Access-Origin:*')
 or send it with the request from ionic as options that take new HttpHeaders().set('Allow-Access-Origin:*'); 
And thats all.Any more details i'm ready.

Comment: how i add that one

Comment: What is the programing language for you api backend?